# JDBI getting argument class in ResultSetMapper

Tags: java, dropwizard, jdbi

I am using Dropwizard with JDBI. I have a typical dao for user data:

```
public interface UserDao
{
  @SqlQuery("select * from users where role = :id")
  @Mapper(UserMapper.class)
  String findNameById(@BindBean Role role);
}
```

The user itself has an attribute with a `Role` type:

```
class User
{
    private Role role;

    /* the rest: other attributes, getters, setters, etc. */
}
```

Role is contained in another table called `roles`. Now, I need to map `Role` in the mapper, but I do not want to change the `SELECT ...` statement to add the `JOIN roles ...` part. We all know how joins affect queries and in the long run I'd like to avoid any joins if possible.

I know, that `ResultSetMapper` interface has a `map()` method, which gets a `StatementContext` passed to it. That context has a `getBinding()` method, which returns a `Binding` class with all the data I need:

```
named = {HashMap$Node@1230} size = 3
  0 = {HashMap$Node@1234} "id" -> "1"
  1 = {HashMap$Node@1235} "name" -> "TestRole"
  2 = {HashMap$Node@1236} "class" -> "class com.example.Role"
```

But that `class com.example.Role` is not an instance of `Role`, it's an instance of `Argument` and I can't work with it.

So, is there a way to get that `Role` argument and I just don't see it or do I have to instantiate it (again...) from the binding arguments (obviously they are there as debugger shows)?

Comment: Do nothing with Role on a first time, then add a method get Role to set the Role of your user. By the way, if your jointure has performance issue I think you have an index issue

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say. Add a get method where?

Comment: I don't get if your are trying to get a `List` of `User` with the `Role` set, or just one `String`

Comment: I'm trying to get back the `Role` instance of a class I'm sending to jdbi with `@BindBean` annotation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it by using a custom binder. First, I modified `UserDao` to use `@BindRole` instead of `@BindBean`.

Next, I had to create the binder for the role. Here the role is bound manually on separate values:

```
@BindingAnnotation(BindRole.RoleBinderFactory.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER})
public @interface BindRole
{
    public static class RoleBinderFactory implements BinderFactory
    {
        public Binder build(Annotation annotation)
        {
            return new Binder<BindRole, User>()
            {
                public void bind(SQLStatement q, BindRole bind, Role role)
                {
                    q.bind("id", role.getId());
                    q.bind("name", role.getName());
                    q.define("role", role);
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the `define()` method, it is responsible for setting attributes in `StatementContext`, so don't overlook it.

Next, in the mapper I just have to get the `Role` with `getArgument()`:

```
Role role = new Role();
role.setId(1);
role.setName("TestRole");

Role r = (Role) statementContext.getAttribute("role");
boolean equals = e.equals(role);
```

In the debugger `equals` is shown as `true`, so problem solved. Woohoo.